# Horizontal rule/line below the address in letter

Tags: letters

I am new in this community with a problem.
I am writing a cover letter. I need to have a horizontal rule/line that expands through left to right of page just below the email address (above the date). Any solution will be highly appreciated. Also I am not sure which command is providing date in the letter. I don't find any date command in the preamble.

Thanking you so much.

Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\topmargin = -1.5in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight = 10.4in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin = 0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth = 6.8in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
%%%
\address{Money Tota \\
XXXX \\
SH, OH, USA \\
Phone: XXXXX \\
Email: money.tota84@gmail.com} 
\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page


\longindentation = 0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}
{Chair, Search Committee \\

Department of XXX \\
YYYY University \\

Subject: XXXX, Faculty Position} 

\opening{Dear Search Committee Chair,}
Body of the letter first line \\
\vdots   \\
Body of the letter last line \\

\closing{Sincerely \\[3mm]

\fromname{Money Tota}
}


\encl{(i) My CV, (ii) XXX, and (iii) YYY}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working as mentioned. However, I really need a thicker line that matches with the text width (here 6.8in) instead of the width of whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this??  Note I set the date that appears by redefining `\today` to `{4 July 1776}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\topmargin = -1.5in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight = 10.4in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin = 0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth = 6.8in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{stackengine}
%%%
\address{Money Tota \\
XXXX \\
SH, OH, USA \\
Phone: XXXXX \\
Email: money.tota84@gmail.com\bclap[5pt]{\makebox[2.5\textwidth]{\hrulefill}}} 
\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page


\longindentation = 0pt
\renewcommand\today{4 July 1776}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}
{Chair, Search Committee \\

Department of XXX \\
YYYY University \\

Subject: XXXX, Faculty Position} 

\opening{Dear Search Committee Chair,}
Body of the letter first line \\
\vdots   \\
Body of the letter last line \\

\closing{Sincerely \\[3mm]

\fromname{Money Tota}
}


\encl{(i) My CV, (ii) XXX, and (iii) YYY}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can change the position of the line through the optional argument of `\bclap`.